# 'invalid memory address' error with go-mssql

Tags: go

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to resolve, probably due to my inexperience with GO. I have the following code working on one server, but not on another. Here is the code:

```
// Build out the connection string to the database, and then open the connection to the database.
connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d", *server, *user, *password, *port)
if *debug { fmt.Printf(" connString:%s\n", connString) }
db, err = sql.Open("mssql", connString)
if err != nil { log.Fatal("Open connection failed:", err.Error()) }
err = db.Ping()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Cannot connect: ", err.Error())
    return
}

rows, _ := db.Query( "SELECT Zip FROM Zip_Rural WHERE Zip = ?", ZipCode[0:5] )
defer rows.Close()

if !rows.Next() {
    acreageRequirement = .5
}
```

On the line that reads `if !rows.Next()` I get the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x20 pc=0x477918]
```

This same code works just fine on another server, running GO version 1.4.2 on both machines. I have a feeling I just have some bad syntax somewhere in here, but have no idea what the real problem is. A call to `db.Exec` within the same file works just fine, which leads me to believe that my database connection is perfectly fine, but for some reason `db.Query` is not executing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an error with `db.Query`. Check your error and if it is not `nil`, assume that `rows` is `nil`. i.e. calling `rows.Next()` will segfault.
If you display the error, you will probably find out what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I get for being a noob. The default database for my user was incorrect, so the .Query was failing with a "table doesn't exist" style error. Changed the default database for the login, and it's processing now. Thanks :).